# How to use a class as parameter in templates in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-specialization

A:
I use something like this:

In Class1.h:

```
template <class T>
class Class1 : Database {
public:
    Class1();
};
```

In Class1.cpp:

```
#include "Class1.h"

template <typename T>
Class1<T>::Class1(){
   //Some code
}
```

Calling class:

```
#include "Class1.h"

Class1<Class2> *class1 = new Class1<Class2>();
```

If i run this, the linker is not able to find "Class1".

B:
When i use something like this:

```
#include "Class1.h"

template <> Class1<Class2>::Class1(){}
```

The linker is able to find it.

**My problem is, that i need to use A in my code and not B.**

**That means i don't want to use:**

```
template <> Class1<Class2>::Class1(){}
```

**I Want to use ONLY:**

```
template <typename T>
Class1<T>::Class1(){
   //Some code
}
```

All tutorials say that i use it correctly and it has to work. Can anybody help me?

Comment: missing `};` for `Class1` is probably a typo - right? Otherwise your code is fine, as long as you put Class1 and its method definitions in header file.

Comment: Thx for the fast answer. Yes the }; i forgot to write here. I have it in my code.  class and method prototype are in header file. the rest is in cpp file.

Comment: Since you split your template code across multiple source files, my guess is that you are trying to use the template in a translation unit that is unaware of the said template's members definitions

Comment: @Byteventurer Not if the definitions are in a `.cpp` file that specifies explicit instantiations. Oh good, now it's deleted, and I'm talking to myself. This was in response to the assertion that definitions _must_ be put in a header file. That's not true. _Many_ of them must, but it's not a strict rule, if you know ahead of time what you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: I have to make something clear. When i use my code for example with int by: Class1<int> it works very well as soon i use Class1<Class2> the linker does not find it as long as i do not give the spcialisation to the code. But i need a solution without spcialisation.

Comment: I suggest  you edit your answer to show us a real minimum example with your file configuration: template header, template "cpp" file, test case "cpp" file...

Answer (score 6):

When you try to instantiate a specialization of a class template, the compiler needs to have access to every member definition, otherwise it is unable to generate the corresponding code (a C++ template is basically a copypasta factory on steroids).

Since you split the implementation details into a separate file, you cannot instantiate your specific specialization a.k.a. `Class1<Class2>`. I suppose you put the `template <> Class1<Class2>::Class1() {}` bit in the header file? If so, your code compiles because it has a full specialization for `Class2` with an available constructor when you use it in your sample.

Schematically you have:

> Template Header -> included in -> test sample cpp file
>   \-----------------------> included in -> Template Implementation cpp file

You can see that all the actual implementations for your template are not reachable within your test sample translation unit.

Comment: When i use my code for example with int by: Class1<int> it works very well as soon i use Class1<Class2> the linker does not find it as long as i do not give the spcialisation to the code. But i need a solution without spcialisation.

Comment: @JOnathanJOnes That's probably your compiler being too generous in situations where it can do so. The proper, portable way to make a templated class is to expose all the definitions in the header file.

Comment: TMP means either temp, Template MetaProgramming or  Thermomechanical Pulp (well, I admit there's loads of other meanings) but using it to mean "template" is a bit of a stretch...

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, `Class1` is a templated class, so you should put you contructor in the header file, not in a separated cpp file.
Otherwise, you can put the constructor in the cpp file where you use it, but only if you use it only in a single cpp file.

The problem is that when you write

```
Class1<Class2> *class1 = new Class1<Class2>();
```

you're asking the compiler to call (and construct) a constructor for `Class1<Class2>` but the compiler don't know how to construct it because it's defined in another file (the compiler, in this phase, see only "Class1.h"; doesn't know the content of "Class1.cpp").

Your solution B

```
template <> Class1<Class2>::Class1(){}
```

works because you're defining a constructor specialization for `Class1<Class2>`, so the compiler know it

Solution: delete

```
template <typename T>
Class1<T>::Class1(){
   //Some code
}
```

from "Class1.cpp" and put it in "Class1.h".

p.s.: sorry for my bad English.